# send facebook notification and then delete it using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-rest-api

I am having a facebook app and the app_access_token for that.

and I am sending a notification to some user using graph api and it gives me success equals to true as the response.
Now, I want to delete the notification I just sent.
How is this possible.
Please, help me.

Thanks,
Amit Chaudhary

Answer (score 1):

Amit, you can try the 'delete' method (in place of 'post' method, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) with the id of the notification using FB.api.

However, what is the procedure you have used to post the notification -- please provide clear step by step direction? This is still an open question here. Specifically, how did you get the app_access_token? Is there any reference that has the list and documentation of different types of tokens/permissions?